# Unable to mention the security group ID for auto scaling launch configuration

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have setup an Elastic Beanstalk, and I'm trying to do an EB deploy, and I'm not using default VPC.
As per the
[aws docs here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/command-options-general.html#command-options-general-autoscalinglaunchconfiguration). (Scroll to security groups)
It says to mention the security group ID instead of security group names when not using default VPC

"If you use Amazon Virtual Private Cloud (Amazon VPC) with Elastic Beanstalk so that your instances are launched within a virtual private cloud (VPC), specify security group IDs instead of security group names."

In my .ebextensions/myapp.config

```
aws:autoscaling:launchconfiguration:
    SecurityGroups: "security_group_id"
```

Still I keep getting value cannot be empty, looks like I'm not properly mentioning it in the structure that it expects, and let me tell you that I searched for that structure, some example codes for the above, but couldn't find any.

ERROR   Updating Auto Scaling group named: awseb-e-5trtffbcqs-stack-AWSEBAutoScalingGroup-B8E7D8RYEMXL failed Reason: You must use a valid fully-formed launch template. Value () for parameter groupId is invalid. The value cannot be empty (Service: AmazonAutoScaling; Status Code: 400; Error Code: ValidationError; Request ID: 8a8b46c3-8129-47ff-9e55-e087085c5a9c; Proxy: null)
2023-06-29 12:10:40    ERROR   Failed to deploy application.

Answer (score 1):

Double-check the ID is correct in `.ebextensions/myapp.config`.

Make sure the Security Group ID is in the same region and the same VPC as your EB app.

There may be a formatting error in the .ebextensions/myapp.config file: The aws:autoscaling:launchconfiguration: section in the config file should be indented correctly.

Example:

```
aws:autoscaling:launchconfiguration:
  SecurityGroups: sg-03a2de7e
```

Comment: If you don't mind, can you please share that code structure? I searched almost everywhere, couldn't find it.

Comment: I have updated the answer with an example.